# Can I play chess on my Mac from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, games

If I were feeling insufficiently geekish on any particular day, and thus found the GUI Chess App to lack an appropriate amount of tech credibility, is there a way to play chess on my Mac from the command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! The OS X Chess app relies on the [sjeng](http://sjeng.org/) engine, which has a command line version. Type `/Applications/Chess.app/Contents/Resources/sjeng.ChessEngine` and press enter to play:

[image]

Make moves with the coordinates of the origin and destination you want: `e1e4` moves the piece at e1 to e4.

Sjeng doesn't take any command line arguments, but you can edit the config file (stored in `/Applications/Chess.app/Contents/Resources/sjeng.rc`). This will probably mess with your settings in the GUI Chess app; make a backup before editing.

Comment: It's worth noting that running this app may create files such as "bug_LE.lrn", "losers_LE.lrn", "standard_LE.lrn", and "suicide_LE.lrn" on your system. These files are safe to delete.